# what's the best way to display images in qt? also I would like to zoom in to particular areas as well

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, macos, qt4

I've been using label to display images. I'd like to be able to click and create a bounding box then be able to drag the cursor to move around in the image. What would I need to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I think the `QGraphicsScene` is what you are looking for. You can (among many other things):

- Render images (`QGraphicsPixmapItem`, for example)
- Change the zoom level when rendering the scene on a `QGraphicsView`.
- Select things using a "rubber band"
- Move items around with the mouse (see `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`)
- etc.

Comment: How would I got about creating a comparator. Where I have two images on top of each other. I will have a slider to expose 50% of each and whenever I slide it to I can see more of one picture and vice versa. Also if I move one picture I would like to move the other by the same amount. How would I do that with the graphics library?

Comment: Every `QGraphicsItem` has an opacity you can set. To move them at the same time, add them both to the same `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get familiar with Qt's [graphics view framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/graphicsview.html).